# Copy paste text from RMarkdown-generated PDF?

Tags: r, r-markdown, tidyverse

If we open a PDF generated through RMarkdown, how can we copy/paste text directly from such a PDF to another text editor?

#### Examples

If we open [part_1.pdf](https://github.com/rstudio-conf-2020/applied-ml) in preview and copy/paste some text, I see blank space (where there should be text), and if we open the same file in chrome, we see some garbled text like

> ++++''$$ ##$$))  --))$$))""

Which should be

> Applied Machine Learning

#### Question

Is there an easy way to open and copy/paste from a PDF generated via RMarkdown?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that you will occaisionally encounter with pdf text extraction. The pdf format can handle several different font types, and it handles them in different ways. In the case of your document, the font of the text in question is a type0 (PostScript) font

Often, the page description program in the pdf will output strings in low-value, non-ascii bytes. These are then looked up in the font's encoding dictionary and the appropriate glyph is pulled from the font description program, which is embedded in the file. Your font doesn't have an Encoding dictionary - it is labelled as Identity-H. Usually that means it will have a ToUnicode entry instead, and indeed yours does - but it is effectively empty.

As sometimes happens, in your case the glyphs in the font description program are not mapped to their proper Ascii value and are just mapped directly to those low byte values (for example, an `A` glyph might be mapped to 0x01 rather than its usual value of 0x41).

So why does the text look OK on the page?

It's because the font description program gets the message to print the glyph `0x01`, but the picture it draws is of a letter A. At no point does the pdf itself "know" the ascii value of what it's printing. Neither does any other program, except perhaps an OCR program.

You are more likely to be able to copy and paste from a pdf you have created if you save it without embedding fonts, or if you use pdf's built-in fonts, which include Helvetica, Times and Courier. However, without some serious reverse engineering, you can't copy and paste from this particular document, and neither can any pdf text extraction tools.